# Divisiblity of an expression by 3

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Doing a bit of work and came across a result I believe to be true but am not sure how to prove. Haven't done much work at all in number theory so any help r tips would be great.

"$2^{k+1}-1$ is divisible by 3 only when $k$ is odd"

Comment: Show by using induction that $2^{2k+1}-1$ is divisible by 3 $\forall k \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: It has to do with the algebraic structure of $\Bbb Z/(3)$, the ring (field, actually) of residue classes modulo $3$. Its structure tells you that if $n\equiv-1\pmod3$, i.e. if $3|(n+1)$, then $n^m\equiv(-1)^m\pmod3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2^{2m} \equiv 4^m \equiv (3+1)^m \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$

Hence, $3|2^{2m}-1$. So, whenever the exponent is even, $3|2^\text{exponent}-1$

This implies that $k$ must be odd for this to happen.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the numbers $2^k$ modulo $3$:

$$\begin{align}2^1\equiv 2 &\mod 3\\
2^2\equiv 2\cdot 2=4\equiv 1&\mod 3\\
2^3= 2\cdot 2^2\equiv2\cdot 1\equiv 2&\mod 3\\
2^4=2\cdot2^3\equiv2\cdot2\equiv1&\mod 3\\
\vdots&\vdots\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider only the following cases:

- $k\equiv0\pmod6\implies2^{k+1}-1\equiv2^{0+1}-1\equiv 1\equiv1\pmod6$
- $k\equiv1\pmod6\implies2^{k+1}-1\equiv2^{1+1}-1\equiv 3\equiv3\pmod6$
- $k\equiv2\pmod6\implies2^{k+1}-1\equiv2^{2+1}-1\equiv 7\equiv1\pmod6$
- $k\equiv3\pmod6\implies2^{k+1}-1\equiv2^{3+1}-1\equiv15\equiv3\pmod6$
- $k\equiv4\pmod6\implies2^{k+1}-1\equiv2^{4+1}-1\equiv31\equiv1\pmod6$
- $k\equiv5\pmod6\implies2^{k+1}-1\equiv2^{5+1}-1\equiv63\equiv3\pmod6$

---

Therefore: $k\equiv1,3,5\pmod6\iff2^{k+1}-1\equiv3\pmod6$.

Therefore: $k\equiv1\pmod2\iff2^{k+1}-1\equiv0\pmod3$.

Therefore: $k\text{ is odd}\iff2^{k+1}-1\text{ is divisible by 3}$.

Answer (score 0):

By the binomial theorem, $2^{k+1}=(3-1)^{k+1}=3a+(-1)^{k+1}$ and so $2^{k+1}-1$ is a multiple of $3$ iff $(-1)^{k+1}-1$ is a multiple of $3$ and this happens iff $(-1)^{k+1}-1=0$ iff $k+1$ is even iff $k$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ is odd then $k+1=2n$ and so the exponent is even and the expression is $2^{2n}-1$.

The polynomial $(x+1)^{2n}-x^{2n}$ expands as,

$\displaystyle(x+1)^{2n}-x^{2n}=(2x+1)\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{n-1+j}{2j-1}(x^2+x)^{n-j}.$

If we evaluate this at $x=1$ we have,

$\displaystyle2^{2n}-1=3\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{n-1+j}{2j-1}2^{n-j}.$

The binomial inside the sum is an integer and so is the power of $2$, so $2^{2n}-1=3a$ for some integer $a$ and therefore has a factor of $3$.

For even $k$, $k+1$ is odd and $2^{k+1}-1=2^{2n-1}-1.$ The polynomial $(x+1)^{2n-1}-x^{2n-1}$ expands as,

$\displaystyle(x+1)^{2n-1}-x^{2n-1}=(2n-1)\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\binom{n-2+j}{2j-2}}{2j-1}(x^2+x)^{n-j}.$

At $x=1$ it becomes,

$\displaystyle2^{2n-1}-1=(2n-1)\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\binom{n-2+j}{2j-2}}{2j-1}2^{n-j}.$